# Javascript to do realtime calculations of add ons to custom packages during form stage

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Still learning so hopefully i can explain the best i can without confusing everyone!

Seems fairly basic, The form i have puts together a package for the user, basically how shopping cart software would work.. The user can select what they need and go to checkout, Well during this process on the (3 out of 5) page, There is a section for the user to ADD Extras to their package. The original designer that helped is no longer able to do so. The code he used is as follows:

**This is an item selected as an extra (So should add £6.80 to total price instantly when clicked the {ADD} Button or in this exact instance deduct the amount from total price when clicked {Remove} )**

```
 <input type="hidden" name="NNRSU" value="" /></div>
<div class="add-ons selected">
<h4>Golf Cover</h4>
<p>Protect against loss or damage up to &#xa3;1,000</p>
<h4>&pound;6.80</h4>
<input type="button" class="selected-remove" value="Remove " onclick="JavaScript: document.qetForm.NNRS_GLU.value='';updateProductData();" />
```

**This example is one of the extra add ons aviable to the user that has not been selected, If the user was to select this item by clicking {ADD} This would add the price shown in the h4 tags (2.28) to the total price in real time, Same if this was then selected as {Remove} the price would then be deducted.**

```
<input type="hidden" name="NNRS" value="AFFGE" />
</div><div class="bolt-ons">
<h4>Adventure Pack</h4>
<p>Select the Adventure Pack</p>
<h4>&pound;2.28</h4>
<input type="button" class="unselected-add" value="Add " onclick="JavaScript: document.qetForm.NNRS_GLU.value='ABBS';updateProductData();" />
```

The problem is.. He no longer can support me so i need to change the code to a basic javascript code, I have seen several out their but all these are done by the user inputting values, As you can see my values are already set so i am just not experienced enough the write a script that will add the value to the total price.

could this be done with getelementbyid?

Thanks, And very grateful for any input / advice.

Comment: i don't quite understand what are you asking. So you want put that 2.28 to your total price? it's in your `updateProductData()` method

Comment: The code currently used;  <input type="button" class="unselected-add" value="Add " onclick="JavaScript: document.qetForm.NNRS_GLU.value='ABBS';updateProductData();" /> can no longer be used as the designer can not support this and help with finishing the site, so my thoughts are to change the current code used to something simple that will for example add the value of the (2.28 add on) to the value of total price.. i can then use the code on all 14 add ons so if the user selects the (2.28 upgrade) or a (5.50 upgrade) the script will calculate and add this to the total price displayed to user

Comment: Randyka i hope that helps, Not the greatest coder! Still learning but i have come a long way in 6 months although it may not look that way!  Thanks for taking your time to help i really appreciate it.

Comment: where you got your total price value?

Comment: <div class="inner-bottom">

     <ul class="price-details">
      <li>
       <span class="price-label">
        Price:  *
       </span>
       <span class="price" id="priceContainer">&nbsp;</span>
      </li>

Comment: i dont see any variable in there

Comment: That is my container for the total price, It is displayed down the Right side of the page to the user. All calculations must be done in the background on same page as there is no POST or GET involved, the users see's the price change instantly when they select or remove what ever upgrade they require. Thanks

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
     /* <![CDATA[ */
     dataLayer = [{ 
     'multiCountry': 'N',    
     'destination': 'UK',
     'tripDatesFrom': '2015-02-06',     
     'tripDatesTo': '2015-02-14',
     'price': '16.51',
     'tax': '2.75',
     'pricePreTax': '13.76',
     'groupSize': '1',

Comment: price is set from page 1 and 2, out of 5 pages, its on page 3 that the calculations are made as that is where the user can select upgrades

Comment: could you use something like this? and set the value of each upgrade to respond with the script, It would be how to display this back in total price that i would struggle, been checking out other posts online and found this..     <script type='text/javascript' >
function startCalc(){
  interval = setInterval("calc()",1);
}
function calc(){
  one = document.autoSumForm.firstBox.value;
  two = document.autoSumForm.secondBox.value;
  document.autoSumForm.thirdBox.value = (one * 1) + (two * 1);
}
function stopCalc(){
  clearInterval(interval);
}
</script>

Comment: sorry, but its impossible for me to help you without seeing your full code. but just advice from me, just update your `updateProductData()` function or create a new function to add your new value(addons price) to exist value(total price)